# 90 day stay in France

Tags: long-stay-visas

If a visitor stays less than 90 days in France, the visitor plans to stay 77 days, how soon can this visitor return to France?? Is it the required 90 day time frame, then the visitor can return, or is it 77 days, etc???

Comment: The visitor can return the next day, but in that case will be permitted to stay for only 13 days.  After staying away for a sufficiently long period of time, the visitor will be able to enter for 90 days again. See my answer here for a calculator provided by the EU, that will help you calculate how long the visitor would need to remain outside the Schengen area: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48282/19400

Comment: The OP didn't mention a visa, perhaps she meant the visa-free travel arrangement her country has with the EU ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 The rules are exactly the same (with the caveat that some visas allow less than 90 days, whereas the allowance for visa-free stays is always 90 days in any 180-day period).